# Sequentially Animating a parameter other than transforms

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a number of curves that I want to control the end bevel factor of in a sequential manner via animation nodes. How can I go about accomplishing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Cheers;

AJ

Comment: maybe a driver?

Comment: If you are asking what I think you are asking then I would agree, drivers would be very suited for this. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by curves, but if you are talking animated graph curves, then it would make a lot of sense to use drivers for it. The first step before getting to drivers however is understanding how you would like to react to the state of your curves. So if you could elaborate a lot more in your question, with specific goals, and maybe some screen shots, it would really help the community here to help you.

Comment: Are those curves separated on diferent objects or they are on the same object?. Please answer this and I´ll post you a node setup ASAP

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanx for answering. They're separate. Is it also doable with a single curve object made up of multiple sub-curves? I'd really appreciate a node setup as I've been somewhat unsuccessful with my attempts :( Thanx man :)